# nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in VFS resource

Tags: spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I am getting below error. Using `<spring.version>4.3.16.RELEASE</spring.version>` and `<spring.batch.admin>1.3.1.RELEASE</spring.batch.admin>`

The dependency below for reference:

Could you please let me know what is the issue ? I am using Spring Batch Admin and Spring project. Any quicj solution is appreciated.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.admin}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-resources</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.admin}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in VFS resource ["/content/XXXXX.ear/XXXX.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/execution-context.xml"]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in VFS resource ["/content/XXXX.ear/XXXXXXXX.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/execution-context.xml"]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/ParameterizedRowMapper
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1533)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1280)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3780)
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163)
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61)
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch Admin is no longer supported and has been replaced by Spring Cloud Data Flow.  The error you are seeing is due to the fact that Spring Batch Admin requires an older version of Spring Framework than what Spring Batch 4 requires.  You'll either need to downgrade your versions of Spring Batch and Spring Framework to versions that are supported or (and this is what we recommend) migrate to Spring Cloud Data Flow.